# C++ find encompassing type

Tags: c++, algorithm, generics

### Motivation

The motivation is, to a certain extent, mimic mathematical notions in C++, mostly to allow extremely generic algorithms to be written. More on the motivation later.

First, some definitions.

### Definition

1. A type `A` encompasses another type `B` if `B` is convertible to `A` at least almost without loss of information*. This is analogous to the mathematical notion of super-sets `B ⊆ A`.
2. A type `C` is closed under `operatorX` if `C` encompasses `C X C`.
3. The closure `C` of type `A` under `operatorX` is the type that encompasses `A` and is closed under `operatorX` itself. `C` might not be unique. `C` might not exist.
4. The closure `C` of type `A` and `B` under `operatorX` and `operatorY` is the type that encompasses both `A` and `B` and is closed under `operatorX` and `operatorY` itself. This requires that `A X B`, `B Y A` and such are defined.

***Note**: This is a pretty imprecise statement, but its hard to give a strict definition without lots of cumbersome restrictions. Just as examples: `int` encompasses `char`, `double` encompasses `float`, `double` encompasses `int32_t` since it has 52 bits of precision, but `float` doesn't encompass `int32_t` since it only has 23 bits of precision.

### Problem

Given two types `T` and `U`, both having `operator+` and `operator*` defined. What is an efficient way to find their closure or emit an error if none can be found?

Note that their operators should be considered to be absolutely insane, that is, `T` might not even be closed under `operator+`, `Σ(k ∈ [0, n)) T` might be a type dependent on `n`.

For example, if we only want the closure under `operator+`

```
closure<unsigned, unsigned char>::type  //unsigned
```

can be easily implemented as

```
template<typename T, typename U> struct closure {
    using type = decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<U>());
};
```

but this is not applicable to all types, since as mentioned, `decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<U>())` might not be closed.

### More on motivation

Say a certain generic algorithm requires manipulation of multiple different types. If we want to create a variable to store the intermediate values, its type should be their closure.

The simplest example would be adding `int` to `float`, using `double` as the intermediate storage. In this case though, the language actually specifies that `float` is the closure of `int` and `float` which is sub-optimal in certain cases.

Now since the algorithm is generic, we would need some way of finding the closure without knowing in advance what those types and their operators are.

I might have gotten a bit carried away and in fact created something stupidly contrived.

#### Notes on title

I can't call it "find closure of types", closure normally means something else in programming :P . If someone would suggest a better name, I'd happily change it.

Comment: How do you want to handle overflow/underflow? `int` is technically not even closed under `operator+(int,int)` unless you view addition as modulo the integer's size explicitly.

Comment: @mindriot signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour ;)

Comment: @mindriot That is also part of the motivation behind this. I would think the ideal closure of `int` under `operator+` is actually something like `long long` or anything larger than `int`

Comment: Yes, and that makes it extremely difficult. What about analyzing `(a+b)+c` where all values are `int32_t`s? The closure of the first operation yields `int64_t`, so without more information about the possible range, the second closure would have to yield `int128_t` even though we know that that is not needed. So, no transitivity.

Comment: @mindriot Actually, if we know at compile time that there is only three additions, their closure would actually just be `int64_t`. This can of course never solve runtime problems, and probably cannot even solve  some compile time problems. It is another layer of check to prevent accidents. Also, this extends beyond just overflow errors.

Comment: Yes, but to even determine (compile time or run time, doesn't really matter) a reasonably tight closure for chained operations, you will have to reason about domains and ranges. For integers, interval arithmetic comes to mind; or you would need to tag your types using some concept of significant digits. Sounds interesting, but very messy ;)

Comment: @mindriot Hence the keyword "efficient" :)

Comment: @mindriot Reflecting upon this for a while, I don't think overflow/underflow detection can ever be baked into this ever, except for a few edge cases which will not in general guarantee overflow/underflow safety.

Answer (score 0):

To get a fairly tight estimate of what size of representation your closure needs, you will have to keep track at least of the significant digits your operations might require.  The following gives an example for integer types only, and covers addition only.  Subtraction and multiplication should be easy to do; after that it will get a lot more messy than it already is. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace closure {

// A subset of numeric_limits provides, just to shorten stuff.  Tells us all we
// want to know about the properties of a particular integer representation.
template <typename T>
struct repr
{
  static constexpr bool is_signed = std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed;
  static constexpr int digits = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits;
};

// An estimate of the range of the sum of two integers
template <typename R1, typename R2>
struct add
{
  static constexpr bool is_signed = R1::is_signed | R2::is_signed;
  // Can use std::max() when on C++14 or newer
  static constexpr int digits = ((R1::digits > R2::digits) ? R1::digits : R2::digits) + 1;
};

// Now the mess: map the required number of significant digits back to existing
// types.  Note that the edge case for two's complement is overestimated to
// preserve my personal sanity: e.g., a char covers -128..+127, but we will
// place -128 into an int16_t.
template <int digits, bool is_signed>
struct result_impl;

// Define unsigned types in terms of signed ones
template <int digits> struct result_impl<digits, false>
{
  using type = typename std::make_unsigned<typename result_impl<digits-1, true>::type>::type;
};
template <> struct result_impl<0, false> { using type = uint8_t; };

// Construct the correct type based on the number of needed significant bits.
// binary log
constexpr int log2(int x)
{
  return (x > 1) ? (log2(x>>1)+1) : 0;
}

// The required type based on the binary logarithm of the number of significant bits
template <int logdigits>
struct logtype;

template <> struct logtype<0> { using type = int8_t;  };
template <> struct logtype<1> { using type = int8_t;  };
template <> struct logtype<2> { using type = int8_t;  };
template <> struct logtype<3> { using type = int16_t; };
template <> struct logtype<4> { using type = int32_t; };
template <> struct logtype<5> { using type = int64_t; };

// And this is the actual type for signed integers with a certain minimum number of bits
template <int digits> struct result_impl<digits, true>
{
  using type = typename logtype<log2(digits)>::type;
};

// Finally, our result type using the representation types from above.
template <typename R>
struct result { using type = typename result_impl<R::digits, R::is_signed>::type; };

}

int main()
{
  using namespace closure;

  // Adding two 16-bit values should require a 32-bit type
  std::cout << typeid(result<add<repr<uint16_t>,
                                 repr<uint16_t>>>::type).name() << std::endl;

  // Adding three 16-bit values should still require a 32-bit type
  std::cout << typeid(result<add<add<repr<uint16_t>,
                                     repr<uint16_t>>,
                                 repr<uint16_t>>>::type).name() << std::endl;

  // Adding two 16-bit values, one signed, should require a signed 32-bit type
  std::cout << typeid(result<add<repr<uint16_t>,
                                 repr<int16_t>>>::type).name() << std::endl;

  // Adding a signed 16-bit and an unsigned 32-bit value, should require a signed 64-bit type
  std::cout << typeid(result<add<repr<uint32_t>,
                                 repr<int16_t>>>::type).name() << std::endl;
}
```

(**Edit**: simplified the relation between the number of significant binary digits and the chosen integer size, thanks to @PasserBy.)

Compiling and running the result through `c++filt -t` should give you something like

```
unsigned int
unsigned int
int
long
```

as output.  It's not much, but maybe it's a starting point for what you are looking for.  When it comes to floating-point representations, it will get a lot more hideous I fear.

Comment: There is a shorthand for this: use constexpr log2, written recursively. This is actually really nice as is, but its not generic enough. C++ might lack the tools necessary, but if we implemented a algebraic structure such as a symmetric group, this should still work.

Comment: Oh,yeah. D'oh! Thanks.

Comment: I fear it probably can't be made much more generic. You would have to define every operator's behaviour (and resulting required maximum range) for every operator you're interested in, I guess.

Comment: I guess the main question is what you expect your end result to be capable of. Do you have a use case? For one, you could easily use something like what I wrote as a basis for more complex, annotated numerical types that implement the operators and functions you want and scale their output accordingly.